# Как исправить ошибку The page has expired due to inactivity?

Tags: laravel

Делаю аутентификацию на *laravel*. 
Есть чистый проект, в консоли ввел `php artisan make:auth`, создал таблицу, подключил ее в `.env`, сделал `php artisan migrate`.

Сайт открывается
[image: Стартовая страница]
Захожу на страницу регистрации, заполняю все поля. При попытке зарегистрироваться выдается страница:
[image: Ошибка]
Погуглил, пишут что надо добавить в форму `{{ csrf_field() }}`, но это уже было и так. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри в файле .env какое значение в SESSION_DRIVER.
Если не file то:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Comment: у меня установлено 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

Comment: еще пишут, что надо установить 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null) и 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false)
Но они и так у меня такие.